# Style “Cannot find resource 'MetroButton” in MahApps for wpf .netcoreapp 3.1

Tags: c#, wpf, mahapps.metro, app.xaml, netcoreapp3.1

I am upgrading a wpf .netframework 4.7 app that uses MahApps.Metro style to a wpf .netcoreapp3.1 app. Afterthe migration I an getting:

**System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: ''Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.**

**Exception: Cannot find resource named 'MetroButton'. Resource names are case sensitive.**

```
<ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- MahApps.Metro resource dictionaries. Make sure that all file names are Case Sensitive! -->
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/VS/Colors.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/VS/Button.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/VS/Styles.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />

            <ResourceDictionary>
                <!--Button-->
                <Style x:Key="SmallButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButton}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,2" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                </Style>
                <Style x:Key="StandardButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroButton}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="50" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="350" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,5" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20" />
                </Style>
```

This worked with MahApps.Metro version 1.65 under .netframework 4.7 but with MahApps.Metro 2.0.0-alpha0748 I get the exception.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: change **MetroButton** to **MahApps.Styles.Button**

```
 <Style x:Key="SmallButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.Button}">
                    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="200" />
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5,2" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
                </Style>
```